# Post a note to facebook fan page wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Going crazy over this. I am using the facebook php sdk. What I want is, to post a NOTE(not MESSAGE) to my fan page wall. I have specified the message, subject, access token and also my fan page id. I have added ALL the required permissions which are `manage_pages, publish_stream, create_note`. I have also added all the required extended permissions in my app settings.
**The Problem**:
The note is being posted on MY wall whereas I want to post it on my FAN PAGE wall. Here is my code:

```
$appId = 'APP_ID';
$secret = 'APP_SECRET';
$returnurl = 'RETURN_URL';
$permissions = 'manage_pages, publish_stream, create_note';

$displaymessage = 'Message part of note';
$subject = 'Subject of note';

$accesstoken = 'ACCESS_TOKEN'; $pageid = 'PAGE_ID';

$fb = new Facebook(array('appId'=>$appId, 'secret'=>$secret));

$fbuser = $fb->getUser();

if($fbuser)
{
    try
    {
        $message = array(
                'access_token' => $accesstoken,
                'message' => $displaymessage,
                'subject' => $subject,
        );
        $posturl = '/$pageid/notes';
        $result = $fb->api($posturl,'POST',$message);
        if($result)
        {
            echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook Wall...';
        }
    }
    catch(FacebookApiException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
else
{
    $fbloginurl = $fb->getLoginUrl(array('redirect-uri'=>$returnurl, 'scope'=>$permissions));
    echo '<a href="'.$fbloginurl.'">Login with Facebook</a>';
}
```

I have looked this up a lot and I an wondering if it is possible to post a note on a fan page as admin? Thanks.

Comment: I think you should use a page access token for that …

Comment: already tried that. Still note appears on my wall instead of the page wall. :-(

Comment: `var_dump($posturl)` – notice something …?

Comment: nope! gives me the posturl in the form '/pageid/notes'

Comment: That is impossible with the code you have shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution. I guess there was a problem with the access token. So instead of specifying the access token, I generated it using

```
$page_info = $facebook->api("/$pageId?fields=access_token");
```

And using $page_info in the array like this
 `$args = array(
        "access_token" => $page_info["access_token"],
        "message" => "Note Body",
    "subject" => "Note subject!"
      );`

I have managed to post the note to my facebook fan page wall! Thanks!